# Excel pivot table slicer selection to show all pivoted columns, not only the intersection for the selected value

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, slicers

I want to apply a slicer for the value and show only the item where this value exists, but also show all values related to this item.

Here is the sample data and the result when the value 100 is selected:
[Sample data and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbZmV.png)

Here is the result that I want to achieve, with the same filter selection. I.E. the item is filtered, but all days and their values are shown:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJfTx.png)

Is there a pivot table option to achieve this. Solutions with DAX are also OK, but I should not use VBA.

I tried different pivot options and DAX, but with no luck.

Comment: Don't you mean to filter on the item rather than the value?

Comment: Filtering on the value, selects the related item, but also keeps all other values related to the item, for all days.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you show in your desired result?